# Is it possible to mention a class inside itself?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object

I've created is a class called `User` inside this class' constructor I want to add the class to a dictionary. Code:

```
users = {}


class User:
    def __init__(self, id_):
        self.id_ = id_
        
        # What I want to do:
        users[id_] = THE_CLASS_DEFINED
```

I tried to make a seperate function called `add_user` which defines the class and adds the class to `users`. Which works fine, but it would be nice if you could define the class and add it to the dictionary inside the class if you know what I mean.

If this is possible please let me know, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you are asking about *instances* of the class, not the class itself. Using the proper vocabulary matters, if you want people to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @chepner guess what, 2 people answered my question and both is what im looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question, you can save `self` as the value in your dictionary

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id_):
        self.id_ = id_
        users[id_] = self
```

Then for example

```
>>> a = User(5)
>>> b = User(9)
>>> print(users)

{5: <__main__.User object at 0x000001FC68D4F780>,
 9: <__main__.User object at 0x000001FC68E7FCC0>}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be precisely `User`, and nothing else, without relying on weird magic, you're stuck saying:

```
users[id_] = User
```

If you want precisely `User`, and you're on Python 3, but don't want to repeat yourself, you can use weird magic (the same one that backs the implementation of no-arg `super`) to make this work:

```
users[id_] = __class__
```

If you want whatever the class of `self` is (which might be a subclass of `User`) you can do:

```
users[id_] = type(self)
```

And if you just phrased the question wrong, and want the *instance*, not the *class* in the dictionary, you do:

```
users[id_] = self
```